# How to check if items with a certain value are part of a SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

While writing a unit test for a model with a `SelectList` property I got thrown off a bit. I had boiled my situation down to the following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void SanityCheck()
{
    var rawOptions = new[] { (int?)null, 0, 1 };
    var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new { Value = a, Text = a.ToString() }));
    Assert.That(selectList.Count(item => item.Value == null), Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

This test fails ("expected 1, actual 3"). But why?!

After some time trying to figure it out I realized that `selectList` is in fact a `SelectList`, so I tried to change my test to be more specific:

```
[Test]
public void SanityCheck()
{
    var rawOptions = new[] { (int?)null, 0, 1 };
    var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new { Value = a, Text = a.ToString() }));
    Assert.That(selectList.Items.Count(item => item.Value == null), Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

This fails to compile with a message:

> 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can appreciate that, as the `Items` property is of the non-generic `IEnumerable` type. But now I'm at a loss of how I *should* write my `Assert`. There's no `Values` property on a `SelectList`, or anything of the kind.

What am I missing here? Is this impossible if I use dynamic objects for my `SelectList`? Any recommended approach?

---

At first I thought I had omitted `using System.Linq;` in my file, but it was there. To be sure there were no side effects causing my issue, I did the following to get the above results in a reproducible scenario:

1. In VS 2012 create a new .NET 4.5 Class Library project.
2. Using NuGet, add NUnit 2.6.4.
3. Using NuGet, add Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 (and mentioned dependencies).
4. Copy paste the code below to the automatically created `Class1.cs` file:

Repro:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void SanityCheck1()
        {
            var rawOptions = new[] { (int?)null, 0, 1 };
            var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new { Value = a, Text = a.ToString() }));
            Assert.That(selectList.Count(item => item.Value == null), Is.EqualTo(1));
        }

        [Test]
        public void SanityCheck2()
        {
            var rawOptions = new[] { (int?)null, 0, 1 };
            var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new { Value = a, Text = a.ToString() }));
            // Will not compile:
            //Assert.That(selectList.Items.Count(item => item.Value == null), Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual result is 3, because you have not set the `Value` property of the `SelectListItem` (they are all null). You are using the [first overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492864(v=vs.118).aspx) of the `SelectList` constructor which accepts `IEnumerable`. This is typically used when the collection is a value type. For example:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() {"Option 1", "Option 2" };
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items);
```

This generates a collection of `SelectListItem` where the `Text` property is "Option 1" and "Option 2" respectively, but the `Value` property is `null`. Used in `DropDownListFor()`, this will generate

```html
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
```

Note that the option tags do not have a `value` attribute (its not required as selecting an option will set the select's value to the option text).

If you use `DropDownListFor()` in your case you will see how weird the output your generating is (you have a collection of anonymous objects and internally the `SelectList` constructors calls the `ToString()` method of each item)

```html
<option>{ Value=, Text= }</option>
<option>{ Value=0, Text=0 }</option>
<option>{ Value=1, Text=1 }</option>
```

You need to use one of [the overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx) that specifies the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField`

```
var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new { Value = a, Text = a }), "Value", "Text");
```

or it could be

```
var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new { ID = a, Name = a }), "ID", "Name");
```

which will produce the following html

```html
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
```

However, internally `null` values are converted to an empty string (necessary to generate the html), so in this case `Assert` would also fail because the actual result will be zero. Instead you will need to check for an empty string

```
Assert.That(selectList.Count(item => item.Value == string.Empty), Is.EqualTo(1));
```

In any case, a `SelectList` should not include an 'empty' option. Instead, you should be using [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561(v=vs.118).aspx) of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts a `labelOption` to generate a `null` value.

Comment: I knew about that last option you mentioned, though I was undecided whether I like that option, because that prevents me from unit testing whether a view will correctly be showing an explicit option for "NULL". In any case: thanks for a clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`SelectList.Items` is of the type `IEnumerable`. In order to be able to perform linq queries on it, you'll need to cast it to some sort of strongly typed generic `IEnumerable<T>`.

I don't think this will however be possible if you are working with anonymous types like you do in your example. Unless you are willing to generate expressions dynamically the compiler needs to know the type you are working with. Because `Count()` is not defined for a non generic `IEnumerable` which is why you are getting the compiler error.

Conversely `SelectList` itself inherits `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, which is a generic type of `IEnumerable`, for which it is possible to write linq queries. I think that under the hood `SelectList` converts your anonymous types you feed to `SelectListItems.Items` into `SelectListItems` instances when you access the instance of `SelectList` itself as an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Is it really necessary for you to work with anonymous types for generating the select list items? Try the following code:

```
[Test]
public void SanityCheck()
{
    var rawOptions = new[] { (int?)null, 0, 1 };
    var selectList = new SelectList(rawOptions.Select(a => new SelectListItem { Value = a.ToString(), Text = a.ToString() }));
    Assert.That(selectList.Items.Cast<SelectListItem>().Count(item => String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value)), Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Note that `selectList.Items.Cast<SelectListItem>()`  fails at runtime if you feed the `SelectList` anonymous types. This indicates that the items in `SelectList.Items` are preserved as they are added.